# Open tab with a custom referrer

Tags: firefox, tabs, firefox-addon, http-referer, firefox-addon-sdk

How can I open a tab with a custom referrer in a Firefox add-on?

I guess something like that:

```
tab.addProperty("referer", "http://mywebsite.com/");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot "add" a referrer to an already open tab, the referrer needs to be specified when the tab is opened. You use [`gBrowser.addTab()` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/XUL/tabbrowser#m-addTab) for that:

```js
gBrowser.addTab("http://example.com/", {referrerURI: "http://referrer.com/"});
```

`gBrowser` is a global variable in the browser window. If you don't have the browser window, you can use [nsIWindowMediator.getMostRecentWindow()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/XPCOM_Interface_Reference/nsIWindowMediator#getMostRecentWindow%28%29) for that:

```js
var windowMediator = Components.classes["@mozilla.org/appshell/window-mediator;1"]
                               .getService(Components.interfaces.nsIWindowMediator);
var window = windowMediator.getMostRecentWindow("navigator:browser");
window.gBrowser.addTab(...);
```

Comment: Thanks you for the example, not an esay acess in tabs libray?

Comment: @MarcosEusebi: Are you using Add-on SDK? Your question doesn't say that. Anyway, the Add-on SDK doesn't provide any way to set the referrer, so you have to use chrome authority and window mediator as in my second example.

Comment: @MarcosEusebi: That creates add-ons with the Add-on SDK. See https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/developers/docs/sdk/1.3/dev-guide/module-development/chrome.html for chrome authority and replace `Components.classes` by `Cc` in my example, `Components.interfaces` should be replaced by `Ci`.

Comment: I understand, but thanks you.
I think something like that:

`var {Cc, Ci} = require("chrome");
Cc.gBrowser.addTab("http://example.com/", {referrerURI: "http://referrer.com/"});
`
Maybe im wrong...

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a URI first:

```js
var ref = Components.classes["@mozilla.org/network/io-service;1"].getService(Components.interfaces.nsIIOService).newURI("http://referrer.com/",null,null); 
gBrowser.addTab("http://example.com/", {referrerURI: ref});
```

Enjoy !